# Get data from array with different index

Tags: arrays, vector, system-verilog

I have the following array in SystemVerilog:

```
reg [49:0] wvu[0:63] = {
    50'b00001111111101100111101111101010000010000000110011,
    50'b00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000,
    50'b00000000000001000000100100011111110001101001111010,
    //...
    50'b01111111111111111111111111111111011101111111111111
};
```

The bit width of 50 and the 64 elements are not fixed numbers and they can be different for a different application. It is not desirable to change the bit width for different applications, therefore I have fixed it to 32 bits:

```
reg [31:0] wvu_prime [0:100] = {
    32'b00001111111101100111101111101010,
    32'b00001000000011001100000000000000,
    32'b00000000000000000000000000000000,
    32'b00000000000000000100000010010001,
    32'b11111100011010011110100000000000,
    //...
    32'b00000000000000011111111111111111,
    32'b11111111111111011101111111111111
};
```

The data of `wvu` and `wvu_prime` is the same and if I would concatinate all elements of `wvu` and concatinate all elements of `wvu_prime`, they would both become two 3200 bit regs which are exactly the same.

Now my question is, how can I get data from `wvu_prime` with the indexes of `wvu`? For example, I can access the range of bits `y:z` of element `x` of `wvu` using `wvu[x][y:z]`. How can I get the same data from `wvu_prime`? Result should be synthesizable.

Comment: @Mikef I think it is also possible to make a relation between e.g. 50 and 32, but then I need to concatinate ranges of sometimes 2 elements and sometimes 3 elements. E.g. if I want to take wvu[0][49:0] from wvu_prime, then I have to concatinate wvu_prime[0][31:0] with wvu_prime[1][31:14]. To take wvu[1][49:0] from wvu_prime, I have to concatinate wvu_prime[1][13:0] with wvu_prime[2][31:0] with wvu_prime[3][31:28] etc. I am trying to find a pattern/relation in this and then I can make a function which does this in SystemVerilog.

Comment: It should be synthesizable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a packed union for this.

```
union packed {
  logic [0:63][49:0] wvu;
  logic [0:99][31:0] wvu_prime;
} data;
```

Then for example, you can access `data.wvu[3][10:5]` which maps to `{data.wvu_prime[5][2:0],data.wvu_prime[6][31:29]}`.

This should be synthesizable, but I would check with your tool before getting too far into your design. Also check for timing and area. You may need to break this up into multiple clock cycles.

Comment: It looks like Vivado 2018.3 and on support unions (according to UG 901 Synthesis Guide).